# How to get confidence estimate of random forest model predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, confidence-interval, random-forest

I am working on binary classification using random forest model with dataset shape of 977, 6. Class proportion is 77:23

I built the ML model using my input data and obtained the probabilities of the outcome using `predict_proba` function from the `scikit-learn` package.

However, I want to know whether we can get the confidence of the model predictions?

For example, I am expecting my output to be something like below

[image]

Currently, I ran the predict_proba function once on test set, so I have computed the probability once. So, am not sure how can we find out the confidence of our model predictions? Is there any python package that can help us get this sort of confidence?

Comment: You made that third “confidence” column yourself, right? What would you like it to mean?

Comment: Yes, I made the 3rd column. I want to know how much we can rely on model predictions? For ex: If business asks us, how can we know/trust that model prediction correct? So, I felt having something like confidence score can help. For ex: As a normal human being, sometimes, we use this term during conversation on some topics,. For example, I would say that "I am 100% confident that we would get veggie burger in Mcdonald". For someone who is not aware of Mcdonald or reluctant to go to Mcdonald, they may even be positively influenced to accept what I say. So, I was thinking on those lines.

Comment: my example is a cooked up example though. there could be better way or better examples  but currently I can't think of any. I was looking at calibration curves. My calibration score was `0.22`...NOT SURE whether it is useful here

Comment: You are asking for a prediction interval, not a confidence interval. This question has been asked and answered before; see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/562058/237901).